# UICollectionViewController Calling DataSource method of another UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have implemented custom `UITabBarController`
First and Second `UITabBarItem` is a `UICollectionViewController`
Fourth `UITabBarItem` is a `UIViewController`

CollectionView in 1st tab and its cell is created programmatically and working perfectly with dynamic cell size.

CollectionView methods in the 2nd tab are not edited.

**Problem:** App launched and 1st CollectionView is loaded with a cell, then I go to 2nd Tab which is also a CollectionViewController which does not have any cell, then I go to 1st tab again and the cell on 1st UICollectionview won't display.

**Things I noticed:**

1. Added debug point on `collectionview` methods in both VC. 1st tab VC is calling methods of 2nd VC(Strange!) after I move from 2nd tab to 1st.
2. Going to Fourth tab (`UIViewController`) and then back to 1st does not cause any problem.

**Solution I tried:**

1. Register cell of 1st VC in `viewWillAppear` (it used to crash at `dequeueReusableCell` but now doesn't crash after assigning tag and checking it in cellForItemAt)
2. Assign tag to both `collectionview` in both VC and check for `collectioniView.tag` in methods of both VC, but 1st tab VC is still calling methods in 2nd tab VC

**Edit 1:**
called in `viewWillAppear()`

```
SetupCollectionView(){
  collectionView?.register(VideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        self.collectionView?.delegate = self
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
}
```

CollectionView Methods in 1st VC

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if collectionView.tag == 339 {
                print("videos.count: \(self.videos.count)")
                if videos.count > 0 {
                    return self.videos.count
                }else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
            return 0
        }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            if collectionView.tag == 339 {
                //setup cell to display
            }else{
                let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
                return cell2
            }
        }
```

same check is performed in `sizeForItemAt` and 2nd VC.

**Edit 2:**

1. in AppDelegate

   `self.window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()`
2. in CustomTabBarController

1st VC

```
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let homeController = HomeControllerMain(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        let homeViewNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
        homeViewNavController.tabBarItem.title = nil
        homeViewNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home1")
        homeViewNavController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home")
        homeViewNavController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
```

2nd VC

```
let commentController = searchMainViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
let commentViewNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: commentController)
commentViewNavController.tabBarItem.title = ""
commentViewNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "search1")
commentViewNavController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "search")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
commentViewNavController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
```

Comment: You should include your code

Comment: will you please specify which vc's code you would like to see?

Comment: all those that are involved.. but the relevant code should suffice (wiring up of collectionViews and their cells, etc.)

Comment: Added the code i'm using

Comment: try setting debugger in 1st vc since it seems like numberOfItems returning 0. also in your cell for item method: "  if collectionView.tag == 339 {
                //setup cell to display
            } ", you are not returning any cell, that could be the point for crash. check with debugger

Comment: the code is working fine and displays the cell perfectly when im in 1st VC. i have printed number of items in numberOfItemsInSection() and its displaying correct number of values even after i return from 2nd VC to 1st.

Comment: I have returned the cell where i wrote the comment. i ommited the code here coz it is working fine -> collectionView.tag == 339 { //setup cell to display }.
if you think //setupCellToDisplay might contain issue then let me know i will add it in a question

Comment: How are you initializing the TabBarController?

Comment: @Mukesh
I am using itsKaynine/SwiftRaisedTab(which is UITabBarController) for raised center tab item and then creating subclass 'CustomTabBarController()' of SwiftRaisedTab.
Please check the code in Edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I was using single `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` variable in both *homeController* and *commentController*.

Created second `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` variable for *commentController* and problem solved.